# Проверить наличие одного символа перед другим Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Добрый день! Очень интересная задача! Как проверить наличие одного символа перед другим. То есть запретить ввод $ перед ?, и разрешить после. Не обязательно запрещать сам ввод. Достаточно проверить их положение и получить Bool. Очень интересно как делать! Идей вообще нету!

Comment: Я так понимаю что строку в любом случаи раскладывать в массив!!!

Comment: эта задача не очень интересная. видимо надо пройтись for'ом через строку и проверить. в случае, если речь идет про ввод в текстовое поле, тогда проверить последний введенный символ, и если он '?' то проверить символ перед ним

Answer (score 0):

Ничего сложного или интересного:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let lastCharacter = textField.text?.characters.last
    if lastCharacter == "?" && string == "$" {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Это если добавляется новый символ в конец строки, для изменения строки нужно будет слегка доработать.

Comment: предположу, что он может добавляться в любое место строки, и не забудьте про copy-paste (вся строка может измениться)

Comment: Конечно, я всего лишь показал простейший пример, а автор пусть уже сам доработает под свои нужды - для этого достаточно почитать о параметре range в этом методе и немного посидеть подумать (может быть даже с бумагой и ручкой).

Comment: Не проверка по последнему символу не покатит. Что мне мешает потом вставить символ после того когда функция вернет true. Туту надо однозначно в массив раскзадывать. Только как запретить ввод символа после того как я например проверю ввод ? и получу true...

Comment: Не простая задача...

Comment: Это метод делегата, он вызывается каждый раз, когда происходит редактирование текстфилда. Советую почитать о делегировании, хотя бы это - http://swiftbook.ru/blog/how-delegation-works